# How to make 100% sure your certificate is compatible with Salesforce

Tags: callout, certificates

We recently had a certificate signed by DigiCert to used in a 2-way SSL integration with a partner.  While it's root certificate is trusted by SF, the intermediate is not  ([see previous post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51218/salesforce-intermediate-certificate-chain))

Despite what the SF support agent says, as far as we can tell, SF does not seem to correctly send the certificate in requests.  It appears [others have had this issue as well](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8749/two-way-authentication-and-ssl-certitificates).

We have decided to go ahead and resign the certificate with another CA.

**How can we ensure that we don't run into this issue again (that the entire certificate chain will be trusted by SF)?**

Answer (score 1):

First thing is match exact certificate name string from Salesforce supported certificates. Include all immediate certificate to root certificate in chain.

Suppose my certificate chain is:

> Equifax Secure CA --> GeoTrust Global CA --> RapidSSL CA  ( This we
>   bought)

So all of these three certificates must be in SFDC accepted certificate list to make 100% surety.

Comment: Do most CA's give you this level of control when signing certificates?